# Opening two times when I move in a new viewController

Tags: xcode, swift4.2

I am  using the following method to move between viewControllers:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueJokeDetail", sender: self)
}
```

That's the capture from the storyboard showing segueId

[image: Capture]

Answer (score 1):

If you do a segue from a UITableViewCell in interface builder, you don’t need to do it in the UITableView delegate as well.

Comment: No problem. You are welcome.  Can you please accept it as a working answer?